# How to find "local users and groups" from the search bar?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, windows-search

I'm using Windows 7 professional. I would like to have the "local users and groups" snap-in icon show up, when I search for search terms like "users" or "groups" or even "local users and groups".

[image: Search results for "local users and groups"]

How can I accomplish that?

I know I can get the snap-in typing lusrmgr.msc, but that is not the question.

Search for (some?) other snap-ins work fine. For instance the task scheduler:

[image: Search for "Schedule"]

**EDIT:**

I have now tested searching from 3 machines. The behavior seems to differ. One machine actually behaves as I would like. (This machine is a part of a domain - could this make a difference?). On the two other machines the "edit local users and groups" does not show up in search. Not even when searching from the control panel.

[image: Search for "Users" working as expected]

Where can I adjust the behavior of windows search?

Comment: Is the problematic installation a non-English installation that was later made English by installing a MUI pack or something like that?

Comment: No, the operating system is US English and has not changed.

Comment: On the installation where the issue happens, are you using an account with limited privileges? I'm wondering if it might be a permissions thing.

Comment: I don't think that this is a permission issue. The issue exist on two installations. On both machines I log in with an Administrator user.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a link to `lusrmgr.msc` with your desired search words `local users and groups`.